# operator does not exist: text = bigint with Nodejs and Postgresql

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sql-update

I keep getting the error "error: operator does not exist: text = bigint" when attempting to update the email column for a user with a certain id and cid. Any advice would help! Thank you. If you know how to check for if the token is present that would be helpful as well because I am passing it. Here is my code:

```
const  bcrypt  =  require("bcrypt");

const  client  =  require("../configs/database");

const  jwt  =  require("jsonwebtoken");

exports.updateemail  =  async (req, res) => {
    const { 
        id,
        newemail,
        cid
    } =  req.body;

    const query = "UPDATE users SET (email) = ("+newemail+") WHERE id = "+id+" AND cid = "+cid+"";

    try {
        const res = await client.query(query)
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Success' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE users SET (email) = ("+newemail+") WHERE id = "+id+"...` Don't concatenate variables into a SQL string, this is unsafe - use bind parameters instead!

Comment: I love when someone shows up to my question and just complains about something and offers zero solution.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution and it worked.

```
client.query(
            'UPDATE users SET email = $1 WHERE id = $2 AND cid = $3',
            [newemail, id, cid],
            (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
                res.status(200).send(`User modified with ID: ${id}`)
            }
    )
```